# Crear estructura JSON a partir de POJOS

Tags: java, json, gson

Tengo una duda que me está dando vueltas en la cabeza, necesito hacer un post a un servicios que espera el formato en tipo JSON, pero su estructura es así

```
    { “request”:
    “Message”:{ 
    “Name”:”algún nombre”,
    “Título”:”algún título**”,
    “Correo”:”correo@gmail.con”

         }
                 }
     }
```

Tengo un pojo que tiene name, título y correo, pero no sé cómo hacer la estructura como se solicita uso Gson, para convertir mi objeto a JSON.

Les agradecería una idea.

Comment: te doy la idea de usar Gson para convertir tu Pojo a JSON y visceversa :3

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Entiendo tu inquietud y por ello te aconsejo leas un poco más de Json y Gson, este último investiga como parsear un Object a String y viceversa, eso te dará más contexto.

Volviendo al tema, la estructura que indicas :

```
       {  //Est primera llave indica la data que ira en json 
        “request”:{ //Las llaves despues de la primea son Objetos
          “Message”:{ 
             “Name”:”algún nombre”,
             “Título”:”algún título**”,
             “Correo”:”correo@gmail.con”
             }
           }
        }
```

Por lo tanto tenemos que hay dos Objetos : request y Message, Message está dentro de request en el caso de Message tiene 3 atributos (Name,Titulo,Correo). No olvidarse que esos objetos son llamados en un objeto principal.

Procedemos a crear los objetos:

```
public class Request{
   @SerializedName("Message")
   private Message message;
   
   setter and getter...
}

 public class Message {
   @SerializedName("Name")
   private String name;
   
   @SerializedName("Titulo")
   private String titulo;
    
   @SerializedName("Correo")
   private String correo;

   setter and getter...
}


 public class ClasePrincipal{
   @SerializedName("request")
   private Request request;
   
    setter and getter...
 }
```

Recuerda apoyarte con @SerializedName para nombrar a tus atributos ya que por convención en java el nombre de las clases debe de tener la primera letra en mayuscula y en atributos deben de ser minúsculas.

En este punto ya tienes todos los objetos creados solo hace falta darles valor y enviar el string json generado con el gson al servicio a consumir.

Ejemplo:

```
ClasePrincipal clasePrincipal=new ClasePrincipal();
Request request=new Request ();
Message message=new Message();

message.setTitulo("titulo");
message.setName("nombre");
message.setCorreo("correo");
request.setMessage(message);
clasePrincipal.setRequest(request);

Gson gson = new Gson();
String json = gson.toJson(clasePrincipal); //En esta línea generar el string json que pasarás en tu petición.
```

Saludos.

Comment: Muchas gracias Omar, la verdad que si me habia hecho bola en algo que no era muy complicado, gracias por el dato y de esa manera lo pude solucionar.